# Add new column to Pandas Dataframe from functions' output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I wrote function to estimate parameters of simple linear regression. The function produces several outputs. Function inputs are two **lists**. Also, I have initial DataFrame df from where I derived two lists.

I want to add some outputs from function to the initial DataFrame as a new columns or either have new lists outside to function.

for example:

```
def predict(X,Y):
     beta1 = sum([(X[i] - mean_X)*(Y[i] - mean_Y) for i in range(len(X))]) / sum([(X[i] - mean_X)**2 for i in range(len(X))])
     beta0 = mean_Y - beta1 * mean_X

     y_hat = [beta0 + beta1*X[i] for i in range(len(X))]

     return df.assign(prediction = y_hat)
```

Here, mean_X and mean_Y is sample average for list X and list Y, respectively.

Also I tried **numpy.insert()** to add y_hat into not initial DataFrame but into X which I converted into numpy array.

I have no success to achieve desired result so can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem very clear. What are the `mean_X` and `mean_Y` variables ?

EDIT : Added variable declaration.

Anyhow, here's a simple suggestion :

```
import numpy as np
def predict(X, Y, df):
    mean_X = np.mean(X)
    mean_Y = np.mean(Y)
    beta1 = sum([(X[i] - mean_X)*(Y[i] - mean_Y) for i in range(len(X))]) / sum([(X[i] - mean_X)**2 for i in range(len(X))])
    beta0 = mean_Y - beta1 * mean_X
    y_hat = [beta0 + beta1*X[i] for i in range(len(X))]
    df['prediction'] = y_hat
    return df
```

A cleverer way to proceed would be to use the [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function called on your DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your question, you want to use your function in your existing/new column. If that is case, here is one way to do it. If not, then Let me know, I will remove the answer. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

def Somefunction(x, y):
  a = 2 *x
  b = 3 * y
  return pd.Series([a, b], index= ['YourColumn1', 'YourColumn2'])





df = pd.read_csv('YourFile')

df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: 
  Somefunction(x['ColumnYouWantToApplyFunctionReturnValue a'], 
  x['ColumnYouWantToApplyFunctionReturnValue B']), axis=1))
```

Comment: I have function and it does calculations perfectly. My question is that to have that calculated data outside of the function. More precisely, when function runs it does not keep intermediate results explicitly and I want to have these intermediate results  as a new list or numpy array or dict or pandas dataframe(does not matter) to do another extra calculations. Does it make sense?

Comment: How about storing that calculated data by making new column of it?

Comment: That would be nice. As mentioned I tried several approaches but without success to do this what you're saying. It does not matter where I have these calculated data. Important is to have them explicitly in order to do other calculations outside from my initial function

Comment: if you want to save calculated data in column, then you need to return as `pd.Series(y_hat, index=['Y_hatColumn'])` and apply that function in your dataframe.